# Check if the selected dataGridView row is bold

Tags: c#

I have a piece of that requires to change to regular font and remove from a tracker. I need it check if the row is bold but its failing.

```
private void clientDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in clientDataGridView.SelectedRows)
        {
            if (row.DefaultCellStyle.Font.Style == FontStyle.Bold)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(DefaultFont, FontStyle.Regular);
                new_tracker --;
            }

            idtxt.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            emailtxt.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            nametxt.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            packagetxt.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            notificationToolStripStatusLabel.Text = "0 new notifications";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a few extra checks:

```
if (row == null) result = "row is null";
else if (!row.HasDefaultCellStyle) result  = "no row style";      // this helps!
else if (row.DefaultCellStyle.Font == null) result  = "no font";  // may work without
else if (row.DefaultCellStyle.Font.Bold) result  = "bold";
```

I found this to work for rows, where I had actually set the `HasDefaultCellStyle`.